# How to distinguish L & R circularly polarized phonons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, lagrangian-formalism, solid-state-physics, action

I have a certain theory of transverse phonons written in the Lagrangian form with an action $$\mathcal{S}=\sum_k {u^*_k M_k u_{k}},$$ where $u=u_x+\mathrm{i}u_y$ means ***right*** circularly polarized (RCP) basis and $k=(k_z,\mathrm{i}\omega)$ ($\mathrm{i}\omega$ is Matsubara frequency). Then formally solving $M(k_z,\mathrm{i}\omega)=0$ in terms of unknown $\mathrm{i}\omega$ and then doing $\mathrm{i}\omega\rightarrow\omega$ should give the dispersion relation.

But I think this is only for RCP phonon dispersion. (Is this correct?) How about the ***left*** circularly polarized (LCP) one? (R,L not necessarily degenerate in certain cases)

My guess is we should solve for $M(k_z,-\mathrm{i}\omega)=0$ (assuming all things in $M$ is real except $\mathrm{i}\omega$). This is because RCP $u=u_x+\mathrm{i}u_y$ and LCP $u^*=u_x-\mathrm{i}u_y$ are ***related by complex conjugation***. Another way to see is that for real action $\mathcal{S}$ one can  rewrite $$\mathcal{S}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_k {(u^*_k M_k u_{k} + u_k M_k^* u_{k}^*)}.$$

Are these understanding correct? Is it a valid way to account for RCP and LCP?